# Canot load an XML file in Chrome, but It loads in Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, dom

I was practicing my XML ES6 skills for a job, and couldn't open and read an xml file on Chrome.It opened in Firefox and Edge.
I would like to know if there is a special sintax for chrome or If I typed something wrong.

Here is the error mesages from crhome:

**index.html:27 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(anonymous) @ index.html:27
index.html:29 Failed to load file:///C:/Backup/Programacion/Practicas/Javascript%20(ES6)/Practica%203/datos_xml/books.xml: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
(anonymous) @ index.html:29
index.html:29 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Backup/Programacion/Practicas/Javascript%20(ES6)/Practica%203/datos_xml/books.xml'.
    at file:///C:/Backup/Programacion/Practicas/Javascript%20(ES6)/Practica%203/index.html:29:6**

And here is the code:

```
        <section>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <select name="lista_libros" id="lib_list">

          </select>           
        </form> 
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var w, documento_cargado,num_lib;
        var tit, aut, anio, prec;
        var array_libros = [];          
        // Create a connection to the file.
        w = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Define which file to open and send the request.
        w.open("GET", "datos_xml/books.xml", false);
        w.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        w.send(null);
        // Place the response in an XML document (CORROBORAR EL NOMBRE DE DONDE LO PONE, CREO QUE ES UN OBJETO NO UN DOCUMENTO).
        documento_cargado = w.responseXML;
        // Place the root node in an element.
        Bookstore = documento_cargado.childNodes[0];
        num_lib = Bookstore.children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < num_lib; i++){
            tit = documento_cargado.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            aut = documento_cargado.getElementsByTagName("author")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            anio = documento_cargado.getElementsByTagName("year")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            prec = documento_cargado.getElementsByTagName("price")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            array_libros[i] = new Array (tit, aut, anio, prec);             
        }                       
        alert("ssss");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var option, x;
        for(var i = 0; i < num_lib; i++){
            x = document.getElementById("lib_list");
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = array_libros[i][0];
            x.add(option);
        }               
    </script>
```

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Chrome considers `file:///` uri's as cross origin, even in a `file:///` served page - this is some sort of *security* measure .... try using a http server locally ... see how the error states *Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https* ... and `file` is not in there

Comment: Also, all browsers will complain about synchronous XMLHttpRequest - because it is deprecated due to its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks for your help. I am new to XML and I dont understand which part makes this synchronus; also what are you saying about the "http server locally", I am runing the HTML file (this is in an html) from the hard drive int othe browser.

Comment: The synchronous thing is not your main issue - your main issue is the first comment ... but ... `w.open("GET", "datos_xml/books.xml", false);` the false makes it synchronous - but making it asynchronous wont fix Chrome

Comment: Okey. I will investigate a bit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the error message here is

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https

You are loading the file from the local file system, as indicated by the `file://` prefix on the url. As `file` is non of the protocol schemes supported by chrome for this purpose there is only one thing you can do to make this work in chrome: Use one of the named protocol schemes.

The most likely one being http. You would need to setup an http server to serve the files for you, instead of loading from the file system.

This could be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

Comment: ¿Can I use AppServ for this?

Comment: If it can serve files over http it should do. I don't know that particular software, so I cannot provide more input on that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Appserv worked perfectly. Just drag and drop the HTML file in the www folder, and change the filepath to "localhost"/folder/file.html.